# Is Mutah allowed for the married persons?

Tags: fiqh, shiism, nikah-al-mutah

One of the rational arguments that is put forward in favour of *Mutah* / temporary-marriage is that it helps to keep one away from falling into the sin of *Zina*, when he is not able to marry permanently.

Now, my question is:

- Is being a bachelor/divorced, a condition for legality of Mutah in
  Shiite Fiqh? Is it allowed for a married person to do Mutah in his
  normal life? Or is it allowed only under some situations, like when a
  married person's spouse is suffering from a long time ailment or
  he/she is away from home for a long time?

Another related question would be:

- Is it a man who goes into seeking a relationship in Mutah or the act
  of seeking is valid from both directions?

Comment: Helpful complete site: http://www.al-islam.org/muta-temporary-marriage-in-islamic-law-sachiko-murata

Answer (score -1):

According to my thought , i dont think Mutah should be permissable in this world today as it can badly destroy the main respectable family system. It can harm the relationships that men need to carry whole life. Men will easily twist their thinking and take an excuse for mutah . Until Mutah is prohibited at least husband tries his best to develop good relationship with his wife . And thus promote a healthy family system focussing on his other character traits and his responsibilities. Mutah only develops more urge. Thus taking u to a non-serious attitude of life. 
Men should remember they have rights for four marriages in Islam . Hence,if a man's basic need is actually not getting fulfilled he automatically has the right to second marriage for which he can convince his first wife and kids as well his family his parents and the society.  This is beneficiary for all...means the first and the second wife both ,the man himself as well as kids from second wife. Mutah is totally an illogical explanation and can destroy the society.  Its upto men to decide whether how much important sex is for them rather concentrating on first marriage and its responsibilities. If sex is so desirable that u r not getting it permanently in your life ,  your wife is ill or she is continuously in refusal. Or she has no urge or no issues regarding u getting married to another women only to fulfil something that she has no interest in then well go on for second marriage.  Congrats . But Mutah can harm the society if applicable .

Answer (score -2):

Firstly let me state about your second question as a brief answer. As you inquired:

> “Is it a man who goes into seeking a relationship in Mutah or the act
> of seeking is valid from both directions?”

I didn’t find any specific related issue to that, hence, at least it could be said that it is not considered as a haram practice as much as I made research. But perhaps it could be nicer for women to endeavor not to take a step at the first side. (Or perhaps it is not true) / Wallah o A’lamo (And Allah knows better)

But regarding your initial main inquiry, seemingly it is okay, but there should be paid attention to some items regarding Mut’ah which ought or ought not to do, such as:

- Excess in doing it that it can be considered as sensuality
- Being hidden the issue from the family …
- Keeping the respect of the permanent wife (and permanent marriage)
- If it is below his dignity to do this (which is harmful for his
  personality or responsibility …
- Exposing to accusation (e.g. if some people are aware about that,
  then they’ll accuse you as Zina if they are not aware if you have
  done it as Mut’ah …
- Doing it with the girls who are virgin (& it will destroy
  the opportunity of permanent marriage)
- And so forth.

Consequently, doing Mut'ah for a married person would be permissible, but s/he ought to note some points as I termed (Although others ought to note them as well)

Those above-mentioned items can be counted as some remarkable items which I endeavor to state them briefly and approximately. For more complete matters, you’d better refer to the reference below.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.cloob.com](http://www.cloob.com/c/din_chera_va_chegoneh/113973)

Comment: It seems a rational answer but i dont know why downvote for it. may be due to not being based on their interests!